# Json "Validate" for Play

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework, playframework-2.0

For the validate method on request.body it matches the attribute name and value type of the json object to those defined in the model definition. Now if I were to add an extra attribute to the json object and try to validate it, it passes as a JsSuccess when it shouldn't.

```
{ 
    "Name": "Bob",
    "Age": 20,
    "Random_Field_Not_Defined_in_Models": "Test"
}
```

My Person Class is defined as follows

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

Comment: As you noticed, additional fields don't prevent a `JsSuccess` result. That's just how it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you've been using the built-in `Reads[T]` or `Format[T]` converters that Play gives you via `Json.reads[T]`, e.g.:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val standardReads = Json.reads[Person]
```

While these are *super*-handy, if you need **additional** validation, you'll have to define a custom `Reads[Person]` class; but fortunately we can still leverage the built-in JSON-to-case-class macro to do the basic checking and conversion, and then add an extra layer of custom checks if things seem OK:

```
val standardReads = Json.reads[Person]

val strictReads = new Reads[Person] {
  val expectedKeys = Set("name", "age")

  def reads(jsv:JsValue):JsResult[Person] = {
    standardReads.reads(jsv).flatMap { person =>
      checkUnwantedKeys(jsv, person)
    }
  }

  private def checkUnwantedKeys(jsv:JsValue, p:Person):JsResult[Person] = {
    val obj = jsv.asInstanceOf[JsObject]
    val keys = obj.keys
    val unwanted = keys.diff(expectedKeys)
    if (unwanted.isEmpty) {
      JsSuccess(p)
    } else {
      JsError(s"Keys: ${unwanted.mkString(",")} found in the incoming JSON")
    }
  } 
}
```

Note how we utilize **`standardReads`** *first*, to make sure we're dealing with something that *can* be converted to a `Person`. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

We use `flatMap` to effectively short-circuit the conversion if we get a `JsError` from `standardReads` - i.e. we only call `checkUnwantedKeys` if needed.

**`checkUnwantedKeys`** just uses the fact that a `JsObject` is [really just a wrapper around a Map](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsObject), so we can easily check the names of the keys against a whitelist.

**Note** that you could also write that `flatMap` using a for-comprehension, which starts to look a lot cleaner if you need even more checking stages:

```
for {
    p <- standardReads.reads(jsv)
    r1 <- checkUnexpectedFields(jsv, p)
    r2 <- checkSomeOtherStuff(jsv, r1)
    r3 <- checkEvenMoreStuff(jsv, r2)
} yield r3
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid too much boilerplate it is possible to make a more generic solution using a little bit of scala reflection:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def checkedReads[T](underlyingReads: Reads[T])(implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T]): Reads[T] = new Reads[T] {

    def classFields[T: TypeTag]: Set[String] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m.name.decodedName.toString
    }.toSet

    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[T] = {
      val caseClassFields = classFields[T]
      json match {
        case JsObject(fields) if (fields.keySet -- caseClassFields).nonEmpty =>
          JsError(s"Unexpected fields provided: ${(fields.keySet -- caseClassFields).mkString(", ")}")
        case _ => underlyingReads.reads(json)
      }
    }

  }
```

Then you can specify your reads instances as:

```
implicit val reads = checkedReads(Json.reads[Person])
```

This leverages a fair bit of Scala type magic and also the reflection library (that lets you look at fields on classes).

Rather than relying on a fixed set of fields the `classFields` method gets all of the fields dynamically for the case class (type param `T`). It looks at all of the members and collects only the case class accessors (otherwise we'd pick up methods like `toString`). It returns a `Set[String]` of field names.

You'll notice that the `checkedReads` takes an implicit `TypeTag[T]`. This is supplied by the compiler at compile time and used by the `typeOf` method.

The remaining code is fairly self explanatory. If the incoming json matches our first case (it is a `JsObject` and there are fields not on the case class) then we return a  `JsError`. Otherwise we pass it on to the underlying reader.

Comment: Looks like this fails if the case class has optional fields that aren't present in the json, or fields with default values.

Comment: Can you give an example @AlexITC?

Comment: Run this example, it tries to deserialize a case class having a field with default value, it fails with `JsError(List((/value,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))`, the problem is this piece in your code `if (fields.keySet -- caseClassFields).nonEmpty`, it expects that all of the class fields are in the JSON, otherwise, it returns a non empty set with the missing keys, see https://gist.github.com/AlexITC/2a0687b4e7d9d4fc8db53acc4b2e7fbf

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply @AlexITC. This answer shows a way of preventing JSON with extra fields being decoded, it doesn't change the `Reads` in the way you want.

I've modified your code (see https://gist.github.com/sihil/fe48b8a9a3d25b730203abd9ae2894f6) to show that you are hitting the behaviour of the underlying Reads implementation. The Play JSON library can read default value by providing an underlying `Reads` that supports it (as demonstrated).

You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459027/play-json-read-and-default-parameters-for-case-class.