# ScalaJson: Parsing optional values (with default) without Option

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I'd like to parse `Json` file to read values that maybe optionally provided. In case they aren't provided, I have **default values** to fall-back on.

Clearly in this case, the end result is that **I will certainly have a value** at hand: either the one read from `Json` or the default. However as per my current knowledge of [`ScalaJson`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson) (please correct me if I'm wrong), I'll still have to use an `Option[T]` to hold it (because it may not be available directly in the `Json` file). In other words, I believe that while I can supply a *default value*, it will still have to be wrapped in an `Option[T]`

Is there a way to read an *optional* value (with *default*) without having to *wrap* it inside `Option[T]`? I'd like to inform in advance that I have no requirement (in the foreseeable future) to write (*serialize*) my data into `Json`, I only have to read it (`deserialize`) a `Json`.

---

To further elaborate my question:-

I'm using [*automatic-conversion* using `case class`es](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated), so instead of having to use this `case class` with the given `reads` `converter`

```
case class MyCaseClass(optString: Option[String] = Some("None"))
implicit val reads = Json.reads[MyCaseClass]
```

I'd like to use this `case class`

```
case class MyCaseClass(optStringWithDefault: String = "None")
```

Is it possible to write a `read converter` for this `case class` given the same `Json` source? Alternatively, is there a better design choice that can overcome this problem altogether?

---

I'm on

- `Scala 2.11.11`
- `PlayFramework 2.6`

Comment: Which Play-JSON release are you precisely using. At least 2.6.7 support the default values in the generated `Reads`: https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/2.6.7/play-json/shared/src/test/scala/play/api/libs/json/MacroSpec.scala#L290

Comment: Thanks **@cchantep**, I should've looked harder. Indeed there are quite a few questions on this that have already been answered; though this solution seems to be the most appropriate for `Play 2.6.x` as [told by @Aliaksandr Kavalevich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44884127/3679900)

Answer (score 0):

If you use SBT you can include spray-json in your project with

```
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.3"
```

Define the case class

```
case class MyCaseClass(optString: String = "None")
```

Define the protocol for json conversion.

```
import spray.json._
object MyProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit object MyCaseClassFormat extends RootJsonFormat[MyCaseClass] {
      def write(obj: MyCaseClass): JsValue = JsObject(
        "optString" -> JsString(obj.optString)
      )
      def read(json: JsValue): MyCaseClass = {
        json.asJsObject.getFields("optString") match {
          case Seq(JsString(optString)) => MyCaseClass(optString.asInstanceOf[String])
          case _ => MyCaseClass()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

import the protocol

```
import MyProtocol._
```

**Scenario 1#**

```
import spray.json._
val jsonStringOne: String = """{"optString": "testData"}"""
val resultOne = jsonStringOne.parseJson.convertTo[MyCaseClass]
Output: MyCaseClass(testData)
```

**Scenario 2#**

```
import spray.json._
val jsonStringTwo: String = """{"otherString": "tempData"}"""
val resultTwo = jsonStringTwo.parseJson.convertTo[MyCaseClass]
Output: MyCaseClass(None)
```

Reference link : https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Answer (score 0):

Use [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala), it has built-in support of default values for case class fields.

Add library dependency:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-core" % "0.29.2" % Compile, 
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-macros" % "0.29.2" % Provided // required only in compile-time
)
```

Generate codec for your root type and use it for parsing of case classes with default values:

```
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._

case class Device(id: Int = 1, model: String = "iPhone X")

case class User(name: String = "Joe", devices: Seq[Device] = Seq(Device()))

implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[User] = JsonCodecMaker.make[User](CodecMakerConfig())

val user = readFromArray("{}".getBytes)

require(user == User())
```